# Adding eventlisteners in main document class for external classes

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a small project I'm trying to help learn as3. It is a variation from the book Foundation Game Design with Actionscript 3.0. I am using an fla only to have a document class. All art is loaded within the as files. In the book, he just put all the code in the document class, I followed along and it worked as expected. I am trying to break out the code into separate classes to get a handle on OOP. One class makes a background - Background.as, one makes a character - Character.as, and one makes a button, which I instantiate 6 times for 6 different buttons - GameButton.as. And of course there is GameWorld.as which is the document class. Everything loads and shows up as expected. However when I try and add an eventListener for the buttons, I don't get any response. I have tried putting the eventListener in the GameButton.as and also tried it in the GameWorld.as neither of which has worked. Also I pass a reference to the stage when instantiating the various classes, because when I tried to addChild in the GameWorld.as, nothing would show up. I searched the site and found something similar, but it didn't seem to help. Thank you in advance for any advice you my have. Here is the code:

**GameWorld.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import GameButton;
    import Character;
    import Background;

    [SWR(width = "550", height = "400", backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF", frameRate = "60")]

    public class GameWorld extends Sprite
    {
        //public variables
        //Background
        public var gameBackground:Background;

        //Character
        public var catCharacter:Character;

        //Buttons
        public var upButton:GameButton;
        public var downButton:GameButton;
        public var growButton:GameButton;
        public var shrinkButton:GameButton;
        public var vanishButton:GameButton;
        public var spinButton:GameButton;

        public function GameWorld ()
        {
            //Add the background to the stage
            gameBackground = new Background("../images/background.png", stage);

            //Add the character(s) to the stage
            catCharacter = new Character("../images/character.png", stage);

            //Set initial character position
            catCharacter.CharacterPos(225, 150);

            //Add the buttons to the stage
            upButton = new GameButton("../images/up.png", stage, 25, 25);
            downButton = new GameButton("../images/down.png", stage, 25, 85);
            growButton = new GameButton("../images/grow.png", stage, 25, 145);
            shrinkButton = new GameButton("../images/shrink.png", stage, 425, 25);
            vanishButton = new GameButton("../images/vanish.png", stage, 425, 85);
            spinButton = new GameButton("../images/spin.png", stage, 425, 145);

            //Button event handlers
            upButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, upButtonHandler);

        }


        public function upButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            trace("You clicked the up button!");
            catCharacter.CharacterMove(15);
        }

    }

}
```

**GameButton.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class GameButton extends Sprite
    {
        //public variables
        public var stageRef:Stage;
        public var urlRequest:URLRequest;
        public var gameButtonLoader:Loader;
        public var gameButtonSprite:Sprite;

        //Constructor
        public function GameButton (urlRequest:String, stageRef:Stage, xPos:Number, yPos:Number)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef

            this.urlRequest = new URLRequest();
            gameButtonLoader = new Loader();
            gameButtonSprite = new Sprite();

            this.urlRequest.url = urlRequest;
            gameButtonLoader.load(this.urlRequest);
            gameButtonSprite.addChild(gameButtonLoader);
            this.stageRef.addChild(gameButtonSprite);

            gameButtonSprite.buttonMode = true;

            gameButtonSprite.x = xPos;
            gameButtonSprite.y = yPos;
        }

    }

}
```

**Character.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Character
    {
        //private variables
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
        private var characterLoader:Loader;
        private var characterSprite:Sprite;

        //public variables
        public var character_x_pos:Number;
        public var character_y_pos:Number;

        //Constructor
        public function Character (urlRequest:String, stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.urlRequest = new URLRequest();
            characterLoader = new Loader();
            characterSprite = new Sprite();

            this.urlRequest.url = urlRequest;
            characterLoader.load (this.urlRequest);
            characterSprite.addChild (characterLoader);
            this.stageRef.addChild (characterSprite);
            characterSprite.mouseEnabled = false;
        }

        //Set the position of the character
        public function CharacterPos(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):void
        {
            characterSprite.x = xPos;
            characterSprite.y = yPos;
        }

        //Move the position of the character
        public function CharacterMove( yPos:Number):void
        {
            characterSprite.y -= yPos;
        }

    }

}
```

**Background.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Background
    {
        //Private variables
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
        private var backgroundLoader:Loader;
        private var backgroundSprite:Sprite;

        //Constructor
        public function Background (urlRequest:String, stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.urlRequest = new URLRequest();
            backgroundLoader = new Loader();
            backgroundSprite = new Sprite();

            this.urlRequest.url = urlRequest;
            backgroundLoader.load (this.urlRequest);
            backgroundSprite.addChild (backgroundLoader);
            this.stageRef.addChild (backgroundSprite);
            backgroundSprite.mouseEnabled = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> All art is loaded within the as files.

This is not an approach I recommend. There's a reason God gave us the Flash IDE--and it's not to write code! Any time you're spending on layout and viduals in code is just wasted, unless you have an actual requirement to change the visuals at runtime. The fact that your paths are all hard-coded suggests that you don't have that requirement.

So let's step back and imagine that you have a Symbol that contains 6 Symbols that you've created as just Flash buttons (when you select Button as the Symbol type). These will be SimpleButtons, but in the Class below we're just going to type them as DisplayObject. The Class doesn't care what they are, but using Simplebutton gives them up, over, down and hit states that require no code.

Note that the below assumes you have "automatically declare stage instances" off, which is IMO the best way to do things.

```
package view {
   public class NavBar extends Sprite {
      //because you put these on stage in the Symbol, they will be available in the constructor
      public var upButton:DisplayObject;
      public var downButton:DisplayObject;
      public var growButton:DisplayObject;
      public var shrinkButton:DisplayObject;
      public var rotateButton:DisplayObject;
      public var vanishButton:DisplayObject;
      //makes it easier to do the same setup on all buttons
      protected var allButtons:Vector.<DisplayObject> = <DisplayObject>([upButton, downButton, growButton, shrinkButton, rotateButton, vanishButton]);
      public function NavBar() {
         super();
         for each (var btn:DisplayObject in allButtons) {
             btn.buttonMode = true;
             btn.mouseChildren = false;
             btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
         }
      }
      protected function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
          switch (e.target) {
             case upButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.UP));
                break;
             case downButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.DOWN));
                break;
             case growButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.GROW));
                break;
             case shrinkButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.SHRINK));
                break;
             case rotateButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.ROTATE));
                break;
             case vanishButton:
                dispatchEvent(new CharacterEvent(CharacterEvent.VANISH));
                break;
             default:
               break;
          }
      }

   }
}
```

Note that there's zero layout code. This code is dependent on a custom Event Class. I'm going to write that Event Class so that it always bubbles. That way, it can be dispatched anywhere on the display list and received at the top level:

```
package control {
    class CharacterEvent extends Event {
       public static var UP:String = 'characterUp';
       public static var DOWN:String = 'characterDown';
       public static var GROW:String = 'characterGrow';
       public static var SHRINK:String = 'characterShrink';
       public static var ROTATE:String = 'characterRotate';
       public static var VANISH:String = 'characterVanish';
       public function CharacterEvent(type:String) {
          super(type, true, true);//always bubbles
       }
       public function clone():Event {
          return new CharacterEvent(type);
       }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to manually handle instantiation of the Symbol that has view.NavBar as its base class, it will look like this:

```
package {
   public var navBar:NavBar;
   class GameWorld {
      public function GameWorld() {
         try {
            var navClass:Class = getDefinitionByName('NavBarSymbol') as Class;
         } catch (e:Error) {
             trace('You need to have a Library symbol called NavBarSymbol');
         }
         if (navClass) {
            navBar = new navClass() as NavBar;
            //unnecessary layout code here
            //Note that this is NOT the responsibility of the child Class!
            addChild(navBar);
         }
         //instantiate character
           ...
         //by listening to the whole Document, you can add other things that
         //dispatch Character events on the display list, like a keyboard listener
         addEventListener(CharacterEvent.UP, moveCharacterUp);
         //listeners for the rest of the character events...
      }
      public function moveCharacterUp(e:CharacterEvent):void {
          //character move logic
      }
      //other handlers
   }
}
```

Personally, I'd just add the navBar to the stage, and then there's no need to manage it at all (not even reference it with a variable), simply add the event listeners for the various character events.

The root of your problem doesn't seem to be the character code. However, I'm going to give you a few "best practice" pointers about it.

- The convention in AS3 is for Class members (properties and methods) to be camel case starting with a lower case letter. So, `characterPos()` and `characterMove()`.
- Your Class already contains character in the name, so really these should just be `pos()` and `move()` (though there's no need now to shorten `position()`).
- The only thing your child Classes are doing with their references to the parent are adding themselves. They don't need and shouldn't have a reference to the parent for this purpose. It is the *parent's* responsibility to add the Children (or the responsibility of the Flash Player if you use the stage).
- That said, you could give your Character a reference to the parent Class typed as IEventDispatcher and allow the Character to listen to this channel. This concept is called an [event bus](http://www.developria.com/2010/05/pass-the-eventdispatcher-pleas.html).

Note that the reason that so many people do what you're doing is that Adobe failed to document how to [properly use OOP with the timeline](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html). Unfortunately, by the time a few of us [started documenting](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/943/1/Actionscript-and-timelines/Page1.html) that around late 2009/early 2010, the damage was done and everyone assumed that if you wanted to write good code you had to pretend the timeline and stage didn't exist.

I know I've covered a lot of ground, and probably most of what I said directly contradicts what you thought you knew, so please don't hesitate to ask any questions you might have.

Comment: Thanks Amy, this makes a lot of sense. I was just blindly following the book which doesn't use the Flash IDE. Your approach was very helpful.